# How to create a pandas colum with dictionary count from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have an example data as :

```
date        product campaign_type             total_monthly_sale
2019-01-01. Dell      [call, email, call].       5
2019-01-01. Apple     [fax, fax, visit, visit]   4
2019-02-01. Dell      [call, fax, call]          6
2019-02-01. Apple     [email, email, visit]      7
```

I would like to create a new column called 'campaign_dict' which gives the count of the values from the campaign_type column.

The example output is like this:

```
date        product campaign_type             total_monthly_sale. campaign_dict
2019-01-01. Dell      [call, email, call].       5.               {'call':2,'email':1} 
2019-01-01. Apple.    [fax, fax, visit, visit].  4.               {'fax':2,'visit':2}
2019-02-01. Dell.     [call, fax, call]          6.               {'call':2,'fax':1}
2019-02-01. Apple.    [email, email, visit].     7                {'email':2,'visit':1}
```

Comment: Is `campaign_type` list or string ? Because the `.` makes me thinking it's string

Comment: list of strings

Comment: Why do we see a dot in the output so ?

Comment: sorry, not dot.. that was an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame([
    [["call", "email", "call"], 5],
    [["fax", "fax", "visit", "visit"], 4],
    [["call", "fax", "call"], 6],
    [["email", "email", "visit"], 7]
], columns=['campaign_type', 'total_monthly_sale'])

df['campaign_dict'] = df['campaign_type'].apply(Counter)
print(df) 

              campaign_type  total_monthly_sale             campaign_dict
0       [call, email, call]                   5   {'call': 2, 'email': 1}
1  [fax, fax, visit, visit]                   4    {'fax': 2, 'visit': 2}
2         [call, fax, call]                   6     {'call': 2, 'fax': 1}
3     [email, email, visit]                   7  {'email': 2, 'visit': 1}
```

Comment: The column is a counter object, can i just convert it to dictionary.. i tried doing dict(of the pandas column) but didnt work right.

Comment: @StackUser a `Counter` **is** a subclass of `dict`, so don't worry you can't it the same

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
from collections import Counter

df["campaign_dict"] = df["campaign_type"].apply(Counter)
```